# In angular directives, is it preferable to use restrict A or E over C?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm doing a web site for a client that want the site itself to work as a template for other projects. I'm using directives like this one:

```
webApp.directive('layoutSection', function() {
    return  {
        restrict: 'C',
        templateUrl: 'templates/layout__section.template.html'
    }
})
```

The idea is to just put the class inside the element and the directives does the rest. Anyway this method does not seem to be popular. I see that most people prefer to do a custom data attributes like `data-layout-section`.

There is a reason for this? Is a bad idea to use the `C` over the other methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could assume it's a best practice about Separation of concerns: use classes for CSS, `data-` attributes for javascript.

The angular documentation offers more insight about when to use either case: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> Best Practice: Prefer using directives via tag name and attributes over comment and class names. Doing so generally makes it easier to determine what directives a given element matches.